# Why my code giving a wrong output?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am running the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 5+2

int main() {

    int p;
    p = x*x*x;
    printf("%d",p);

}
```

I was expecting `343` as the output, but the answer is `27`. Why so? I am unable to figure it out why it's happening. Please help.

Comment: `#define 5+2` what is that? what is `x`?

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). The compiler should have warned you. Then learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: I have edited my code.Please check again.Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 5):

This is why it's 27 and not 343: `.` before `-`! So look at this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 5+2

int main() {

    int p;
    p = x*x*x;  //5 + 2*5 + 2*5 + 2 -> 5 + (2*5) + (2*5) + 2 -> 5 + 10 + 10 + 2 = 27

    printf("%d",p);

    return 0;

}
```

You would have to change it to this:

```
p = (x)*(x)*(x);
```

Or define it with this line:

```
#define x (5+2)
```

So that the result is 343

As a reference take a look here to the C Operator precedene: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: better change to `#define x (5+2)`. Then using `x` anywhere would lead to the expected results

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for answering :) Can you cite any resource where I could learn about #define and it's functioning?

Comment: @Rishu You're welcome! It's not a define problem, it the precedence of the operators, i put a link in my answer so you can check it out!

Comment: @Rizier123 : Thanks ! Yes, I understood its about precedence.I have no understanding about #define either, could you cite any source if possible.Will appreciate :) Thanks

Comment: @Rishu For sure check this out: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ It's about the C preprocessor Directives (including `#define`)

Answer (score 4):

```
p = 5+2*5+2*5+2
```

ans: 27

use:

```
#define x (5+2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`x * x * x` with `#define x 5 + 2` will expand to

```
p = 5 + 2 * 5 + 2 * 5 + 2
```

and hence you will have `5 + 10 + 10 + 2 = 27`, you have to add parentheses

```
#define x (5 + 2)
```

and then it will expand to

```
p = (5 + 2) * (5 + 2) * (5 + 2) // -> 7 * 7 * 7 -> 343
```

`#define` does not define variables, it defines macros.

You can read about the [c preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) for more information.

Comment: No good reason for downvoting, what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote pal! I haven't much reputation to downvote even. Though I am wondering as a beginner ,was this question really poor one that I got 2 downvotes :) Anyways thanks for answering :)

Comment: @Rishu it wasn't you for sure, but apparently some one just did it becase thy hace so much reputation they want to get rid of it :), It's just that if there is something wrong in this answer I'd like to know.

Comment: @Rishu, you need to read about the c preprocessor, see my answer, now i added a link.

Answer (score 0):

After macro expansion

```
p=x*x*x;
```

will be

```
p = 5+2*5+2*5+2;
```